# Improving elegance Java maps for putting/retrieving items

Tags: java

I have a simple snippet:

```
            String partition = getPath(data);
            if (partitioningMap.containsKey(partition)) {
                partitioningMap.get(partition).add(data);
            } else {
                partitioningMap.put(partition, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(record)));
            }
```

I realize this is already pretty simple, but out of curiosity, I'm wondering if there is a more succinct way of doing these operations without an if-else block.

I'm looking into something like `putIfAbsent`, but I'm modifying the list via `add` on that key. I was thinking about `computeIfAbsent`, but `computeIfAbsent` and `computeIfPresent` are still 2 different calls.

Comment: One alternative is listed directly in the [documentation of `Map::computeIfAbsend`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)): `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<V>()).add(v);`

Comment: I think `partitioningMap.get(partition).add(data);` must be `partitioningMap.get(partition).add(record);`

Comment: If you can use external libraries, Guava has a great [Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) implementation that's perfect for this use case.

Comment: Are `data` and `record` different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple ways you can do it:

Prior to java 8:

```
String partition = getPath(data);
if (!partitioningMap.containsKey(partition)) {
  partitioningMap.put(partition, new ArrayList<>());
}
partitioningMap.get(partition).add(data);
```

In java 8 you can do:

```
partitioningMap.computeIfAbsent(getPath(data), d -> new ArrayList<>()).add(data);
```

Comment: OP's code adds `data` when `partition` exists as a key, and adds `record` when it does not.

Comment: @saka1029 right; my first example is just a cleaner version of what the OP already had. Only need to check if the key exists and if not set it. Then retrieve it every time regardless.no if else needed

Comment: is there a way that you can return a HashMap from that compute if absent code as well? Trying something like Map<String, List<GenericRecord>> result = records.stream()
            .map(record ->
                partitioningMap.computeIfAbsent(getPath(record), d -> new ArrayList<>()).add(record)).collect(Collectors.toMap());

Comment: Might be adding unnecessary complexity that doesn't really need to be there. Simplistic is sometimes the best approach even if its a couple more lines of code.

Comment: Was just curious, but agreed